# How to make as many lists as I want then be able to add to a specific list?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to make as many lists as I want then be able to add to a specific list?

Let's say I want to make two lists one called list one then another one called list two. how would I get it to make multiple lists? Then how would I get it so I can select a list and add to it? For example, I select list 1 and add list item 4 to it. Then if I want to select list 2 and add list object 4 to it will do that. How would I do that?

Here is the code I have to add to one list and one list only.

```js
const inputBox = document.querySelector(".inputField input");
const inputBox2 = document.querySelector(".inputField .inputText");
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".inputField button");
const addBtn2 = document.querySelector(".inputField .addButton");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todoList");
const listName = document.querySelector(".ListName");
const deleteAllBtn = document.querySelector(".footer button");
const todoListWords = document.querySelector("#todoListWords");
number = 0;

inputBox.onkeyup = () => {
  let userEnteredValue = inputBox.value; //getting user entered value

  if (userEnteredValue.trim() != 0) { //if the user value isn't only spaces
    addBtn.classList.add("active"); //active the add button
  } else {
    addBtn.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the add button
  }
}

inputBox2.onkeyup = () => {
  let userEnteredValue = inputBox2.value; //getting user entered value

  if (userEnteredValue.trim() != 0) { //if the user value isn't only spaces
    addBtn2.classList.add("active"); //active the add button
  } else {
    addBtn2.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the add button
  }
}

add();

addBtn.onclick = () => { //when user click on plus icon button
  let userEnteredValue = inputBox.value; //getting input field value

  let getLocalStorageData = localStorage.getItem("list name"); //getting localstorage

  if (getLocalStorageData == null) { //if localstorage has no data
    listArray = []; //create a blank array
  } else {
    listArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageData); //transforming json string into a js object
  }

  listArray.push(userEnteredValue); //pushing or adding new value in array
  localStorage.setItem("list name", JSON.stringify(listArray)); //transforming js object into a json string
  addBtn.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the add button once the task added
  number = listArray.length;
  addBtn.classList.remove("active");
  add();

  if (number > 1) { //if array length is greater than 0
    deleteAllBtn.classList.add("active"); //active the delete button
  } else {
    deleteAllBtn.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the delete button
  }
}

function add() {

  object1 = {};

  let newLiTag = "";

  let LiName = "";

  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    name = listArray[i];
    object1[name] = "";
  }

  for (const key in object1) {
    newLiTag += `<option class="todoList" value="${key}" id="demo">${key}</option>`;
  }

  todoList.innerHTML = newLiTag;

  $('#AgencyDetails').on('change', function() {
    $('#result').html($(this).val());
  });

  for (const value in object1) {
    LiName += `<div>${value}</div>`;
  }

  listName.innerHTML = LiName;
  inputBox.value = "";
}

function load() {
  let userEnteredValue = inputBox.value; //getting input field value

  let getLocalStorageData = localStorage.getItem("list name"); //getting localstorage

  if (getLocalStorageData == null) { //if localstorage has no data
    listArray = []; //create a blank array
  } else {
    listArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageData); //transforming json string into a js object
  }

  listArray.push(userEnteredValue); //pushing or adding new value in array
  localStorage.setItem("list name", JSON.stringify(listArray)); //transforming js object into a json string
  addBtn.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the add button once the task added
  number = listArray.length;
  add();

  if (number > 1) { //if array length is greater than 0
    deleteAllBtn.classList.add("active"); //active the delete button
  } else {
    deleteAllBtn.classList.remove("active"); //unactive the delete button
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  load();
}

deleteAllBtn.onclick = () => {
  let getLocalStorageData = localStorage.getItem("list name"); //getting localstorage

  if (getLocalStorageData == null) { //if localstorage has no data
    listArray = []; //create a blank array

    listArray2 = []; //create a blank array
  } else {
    listArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageData); //transforming json string into a js object
    listArray = []; //create a blank array

    listArray2 = JSON.parse(getLocalStorageData); //transforming json string into a js object
    listArray2 = [];
  }

  localStorage.setItem("list name", JSON.stringify(listArray)); //set the item in localstorage
  add(); //call the showTasks function
}
```

```css
.wrapper .inputField {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
}

.inputField input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.inputField input:focus {
  border-color: #8E49E8;
}

.inputField button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  outline: none;
  background: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.inputField button:hover,
.footer button:hover {
  background: #000000;
}

.inputField button.active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.wrapper .todoList {
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.todoList li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: default;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.todoList li div {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.wrapper .footer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer button {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  opacity: 0.6 !important;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer button.active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#AgencyDetails {
  height: 30px;
  max-width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.addList {
  width: 500px !important;
}

.footer button {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  opacity: 0.6 !important;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer button.active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="inputField">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add List" class="addList">
        <button>
              <i class="fas fa-plus">
              </i>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="inputField">
        <select class="todoList" id="AgencyDetails">

        </select>
        <input class="inputText" type="text" placeholder="Add your new todo">
        <button class="addButton">
          <i class="fas fa-plus">
          </i>
      </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="ListName">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <span>You have <span class="pendingTasks"></span> pending tasks</span>
      <button class="button">Clear All</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use an object whose keys are the list names, and values are arrays of todo items.

Comment: @Barmar I got it to where the keys are the list name but can't figure out how to make the values todo items. I have updated the code above with the updated code.